# ngx-translate innerHTML styling

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-translate

I using Angular 5.0.1 and ngx-translate/core 8.0.0

I have this code in template

```
<p [innerHTML]="'privacyAgree'|translate:{href:'#'}"></p>
```

and this string in en.json

```
"privacyAgree": "Clicking «Registration» button, I accept<a href=\"{{href}}\">the terms</a>"
```

and this code in my less file

```
p{
    color: #8A8C8D;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    a{
        color: #222222;
    }
}
```

but color for inner "a" will not apply because Angular create this styles

```
p[_ngcontent-c3] {
  color: #8A8C8D;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
p[_ngcontent-c3]   a[_ngcontent-c3] {
  color: #222222;
}
```

but ngx-translate create this code

```
<p _ngcontent-c3="">Clicking «Registration» button, I accept<a href="#">the terms</a></p>
```

and "a" tag doesn't have necessary attribute.

So how I can render [innerHTML] template after translation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change `Encapsulation` mode of your component.

Check this question, it had similar problem.

[Encapsulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47742541/im-having-trouble-with-an-scss-selector-that-is-nested-in-an-ng-bootstrap-tab#comment82510465_47742541)