# I'm having trouble with an scss selector that is nested in an ng-bootstrap tab

Tags: angular, sass

I have an angular project and created a component with scss settings that don't seem to select when I'm nesting the selector under ng-bootstrap tab class names.  Why can't I use a selector like this `.nav-link .badge` in my scss?  However something like `.card-body .badge` does select the element.

template file excerpt

```
 <ngb-tab id="projectInfoTab">
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
       Project info<span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">4</span>
    </ng-template>
 <ng-template ngbTabContent>
...
```

scss

```
.nav-link .badge {
  margin-left: .5em;
}
```

Here's the rendered html

```
<div _ngcontent-c3 class="card-body">
  <a class="nav-link active" href="" role="tab" id="projectInfoTab" aria-controls="projectInfoTab-panel" aria-expanded="true" aria-disabled="false">
    Project info<span _ngcontent-c3="" class="error-badge badge badge-pill badge-danger">4</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Which file is that scss written in? It is probably because of encapsulation

Comment: it's in the scss file of the component that the template is in

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is because of Angular encapsulation mechanism. 
When you create a component, it's encapsulation is `Emulated` by default.

Check this link: [Inspect generated css by Angular](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#inspect-generated-css)

When you put your style in your component style file, angular will generate your style with some attributes added to it, so your custom style

```
.nav-link .badge {
   margin-left: .5em;
}
```

will become something like following after compilation

```
.nav-link[_ngcontent-c3] .badge {
   margin-left: .5em;
}
```

and since your `ngb-tab` component probably does not have any element with that attribute, it does not apply to it. 
You can change your component encapsulation by adding following code to your `@Component` decoration.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'your-comp',
   ....
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Another thing you can do is to move this css to the `ngb-tab` component style file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this just because i had a lot of problem finding a solution for when you are trying to apply a style to an element translated with ngx-translate the class doesn't apply the css

```
//HTML
<p class="text" [innerHTML]="'your.tranlation.key' | translate"></p>

//translation keys
"key": "Lorem <span class='sub-text'>ipsum</span>"
```

Encapsulation is the solution.
Hope this help the google search